# Calculate the difference of the time between the date in listBox and present computer clock

Tags: c#, date, listbox, calculation

I want to calculate the difference of the time between the date of the selected line in listBox with the present computer clock. The selected line contains 5 types of different information. When I select the specific line in the listBox, I can choose to calculate the difference of the time in years months or days using the radio buttons and display the result in the textbox by pressing the **Calculate** button. How can I do that? Is it possible to define the date among the data in the listBox?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`ListBox` items are of type object, so you can simply create a class like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Firstame {get; set;}
    public string Lasttame {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date{get; set;}
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
          return $"{Firstname},{LastName},{Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}";
    }
}
```

and then just set you Listbox items like this:

```
var item = new Item {Name = "Jane", Lastname = "Lambert", Date = DateTime.Now};
Listbox.Items.Add(item);
```

You will be able to get DateTime of each item like:

```
var item = (Item)Listbox.Items[0];
double difference = (DateTime.Now - item.Date).TotalSeconds; // or what ever way you want to calculate it.
```

2.You can get the string from Listbox, convert it to DateTime and then do the calculation:

```
string dateStr = listbox.Items[1].ToString().Split(',')[3];
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "yyyy/MM/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double difference = (DateTime.Now - item.Date).TotalSeconds;
```

But I would go with option 1 myself as you have all properties in hand without the need to splits, calculations, and conversion.

Comment: I think I need to choose option 2 since I need to import a text file to the listBox.

Comment: Well, it is your choice, I was just showing possibilities with their reasons.

Comment: I've tried the coding given in option 2 but there is some error at second line and third line. I put the coding under the Year radio button and there are red lines under ParseExact and Date (third line) private void rbtnYear_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dateStr = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString().Split(',')[3];
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr);
            double difference = (DateTime.Now - listBox1.SelectedItem.Date).TotalSeconds;
        }

Comment: Noted, I've changed the coding and there is still got error with the item in third line coding.                                                                                                                             private void rbtnYear_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dateStr = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString().Split(',')[3];
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "yyyy/mm/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double difference = (DateTime.Now - item.Date).TotalSeconds;
        }

Comment: the third line is about the calculation, you do just whatever you want to do, maybe like: `DateTime.Now.Year - date.Year` ...

Answer (score 0):

From listBox get selected item, and from it's text get the Date. Then use DateTime.Parse method to turn it to DateTime. Then you just subtract from DateTime.Now, calculated Date to get TimeSpan, in which you can get Days, which is the difference. The you can calculate how may years it is by dividing by 365, and months by dividing by 30. Or if you wanna by more precise:

```
((date1.Year - date2.Year) * 12) + date1.Month - date2.Month
```

Where date1 is actual date, and date2 is calculated one from listBoxItem. Thats the amount of months which passed from given date.

Comment: how to get the Date from the text?